# Reference request: systole of hyperbolic surface increases in covering space

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a quick proof or reference of the following fact:

Let $S$ be a compact hyperbolic surface and $l >  0$. Then there exists a finite covering space $S' \rightarrow S$ such that every non-contractible closed curve in $S'$ has length at least $l$.

It sounds like folklore/well-known, but I can't find a specific reference. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implied by the theorem that the fundamental group $\pi_1(S)$ is [residually finite](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67355/residual-finiteness-of-fundamental-groups-of-surfaces), which means that for any nontrivial element $\gamma \in \pi_1(S)$ there is a finite index normal subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$ which does not contain $\gamma$.

To apply this theorem, list the finitely many closed geodesics of length $<l$, and let $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n$ be elements of $\pi_1(S)$ representing each such geodesic. Net $N_i$ be a finite index normal subgroup not containing $\gamma_i$, and let $N = \cap_{i=1}^n N_i$. It follows that $N$ is a finite index normal subgroup not containing any of the $\gamma_i$'s. Let $q : S' \mapsto S$ be the covering map corresponding to $N$. Lifting the hyperbolic structure on $S$ to the unique one on $S'$ for which $q$ is locally geodesic, it follows that the systole of $S'$ is $\ge l$.

Comment: Thank you! I have one question: How do you know there are only finitely-many closed geodesics of length $<l$?

Comment: That follows from proper discontinuity of the deck transformation action on the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Thank you very much.